# Does POSIX guarantee that the standard utilities are in PATH?

Tags: path, posix, standard

In [the "Command Search and Execution" section](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01), the POSIX specification says that `PATH` is searched when finding a utility to execute (with some exceptions).  Does the specification mention anywhere that `PATH` will be initialized to a value that guarantees that all standard utilities will be found?

Or do I need to do something like the following to guarantee that I'll never get a "command not found" error when trying to run a standard utility?

```
PATH=$(command -p sh -c 'printf %s "${PATH}"')
```

(see the [POSIX specification of the `command` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html))

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes and no. In a POSIX environment, the utilities must behave as described by the specification. In practice, this means that conforming versions of the utilities must be present in `$PATH`. However, when running your program on a POSIX-compliant system, you may be running it in a non-conforming environment. In practice, what often happens is that the OS has a legacy mode and a POSIX mode, and is in the legacy mode by default. Worse than missing some commands, the legacy mode tends to have incompatibilities in them, such as options with different meanings.

You can retrieve a good `PATH` with [`getconf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getconf.html). Of course, it's tricky, as `getconf` in the original `$PATH` may not be the right one. The Application Usage for [command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html) shows a way to do it:

```
command -p getconf PATH
```

As far as I understand the specification, this is not necessary if you are running your program in a POSIX-conforming environment; and if you aren't running your program in a POSIX-conforming environment, POSIX doesn't apply. However, this application usage can be taken as a recommendation: if this doesn't work, you can feel entitled to complain to your vendor that whatever they are doing regarding the letter of the POSIX spec, they are not complying with its spirit.

Comment: Heh, I didn't even notice that `getconf PATH` in the application usage section.  Thanks!